# HTML/JavaScript Remove DIV Using Input Field + Match By Token

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am trying to remove divs from a document when a letter is typed, but I cant seem to get the logic and/or syntax down. Currently the code I'm using to do this is commented out in the html document with a working version which removes what is typed uncommented below it. All of my code is below. Any help on this would be great.

Again, I am trying to remove a div element based on what the user types in.

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/7us0aBb6)

[CSS](http://pastebin.com/NKhaQ6UC)

[JavaScript](http://pastebin.com/EsfYFt93)

Comment: Could really use some input here :-/

Comment: Could you provide more context, or narrow it down in the code? Also, you could try to pull out some of the content and put it into JSFiddle.net, becaue it will let you embed HTML, JS, and CSS all in one and you can work on it collaboratively there.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to display my code? It's pretty nested so it's not showing up very well on pastebin. The script is about lines 67, 107. The divs its referring to are below, with class=AccordionTitle.

Comment: I'll try to take a look tomorrow if nobody else is able to help you by then. If you could get it into JSFiddle.net instead, that could help a lot.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wd8eq/ Here's the link to my JSFiddle.net save.

It doesn't display correctly through the viewer though. It does however on test on my end as well as on a phone.

Comment: It's too hard to follow what. I'll try to make a slimmed example and post it.

Comment: Nick, I think you need to rewrite your question and provide some different code. Make it easy for people to help you and people will do their best to help. It's not clear what your question is. Are you filtering divs? Making a search? Or when 'a' is pressed a div is deleted? Give some example cases, what action the user takes and what the expected outcome is.

Comment: And with your code, for a problem like this, start from scratch, like @JoshGough has in his jsfiddle answer. Put in just enough html/css/javascript for the problem you need help solving. Your html has 448 lines in it. That is going to turn people away from helping. The problem is hidden somewhere in all this extra code. At the very least remove all the commented out code. If the css isn't necessary to the question/problem, then remove it.

Comment: So using what was provide below as a starting point, this is what my code ended up being. http://pastebin.com/izMXGtsG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure exactly what you are going for, because that code was too hard to decipher.

Here's some code that will remove a div based on keyup. It removes the div that contains the same letter as what you typed. Not sure if that's similar to what you want, but hopefully this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/h2fa4/1/

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head><title>Remove Divs</title></head>
<body>
    Enter a character to remove the div with the corresponding letter:
        <input id="in" />
    <br />
    <div id="parent">
        <div>A div</div>
        <div>B div</div>
        <div>C div</div>
        <div>D div</div>
        <div>A div</div>
        <div>B div</div>
        <div>C div</div>
        <div>D div</div>
        <div>A div</div>
        <div>B div</div>
        <div>C div</div>
        <div>D div</div>
        <div>A div</div>
        <div>B div</div>
        <div>C div</div>
        <div>D div</div>
        <div>A div</div>
        <div>B div</div>
        <div>C div</div>
        <div>D div</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$("#in").keyup(function(event) {
    var val = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    $("#parent div:contains('" + val + "')").remove();
});
```

Comment: This is what it all came down to, starting with your help! Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/DcYd2/

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad it works...but what is it supposed to do on that fiddle? Anything I type makes basically everything disappear.

Comment: It works on the JS for me. It is case sensitive, couldn't figure out a quick and easy way to do a non-case sensitive and I'm on a schedule with other classes to work on :P